# Parent POM with Multiple - Multiple Modules having dependency

Tags: maven-3

We had a relative flat project structure in CVS and post migration to Git we encountered a issue due to how Git repository were checkout. A CVS repository was never checkout, but with Git on Eclipse we see a repository folder under which projects are checkout. This has caused issue with our Maven script.

The new structure is:

[image: New Folder Structure]

I added the `pom.xml` file under `idml` and `leancore` that refer to parent `pom.xml`. the project below `idml` refers the intermediate `idml` parent `pom.xml` and `leancore` refer intermediate `leancore` parent `pom.xml`.

1. How do I define the dependency between 2 Multiple Modules project?
2. What will go into the parent POM to support this kind of structure?
3. How can `AdjHubCore` refer to a dependency in `idml - idmlj2eert`?
4. We would like to build all the module and `war` file from the root parent `pom.xml` file.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "_dependency between 2 Multiple Modules project_"? Aggregator (multi-module) projects can't be dependencies (since they have `<packaging>pom` not `jar`). Basically, sub-module projects are normal Maven projects that can be treated as if they existed just standalone. Your description differs in "_dependency **on** idmlj2eert_" and "_dependency **in** idml - idmlj2eert_". Which is it?

Comment: AdjHubCore  has dependency on idmlj2eert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *idmlj2eert* POM looks like:

```
  ...
  <groupId>idml</groupId>
  <artifactId>idmlj2eert<artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT<>version>
  ...
```

Then your *AdjHubCore* looks like:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>idml</groupId>
      <artifactId>idmlj2eert<artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT<>version>
    </dependency>
   ...
```

An alternative is to use `<dependencyManagement>` in your root POM, such avoiding having to declare a dependency's version in child POMs. Your root POM has to be a `<parent>` POM, direct or transitive across multiple levels, of such a child POM then.

So, that's not different to any other dependency. The Maven Reactor takes care of the proper build order according to (intra-)dependencies inside a multi-module project at the beginning of the build.

Remember, aggregation (multi-module) and inheritance (parent/child relationships) are different things. A project can use either of them and it can use both, too. See [POM Reference, Inheritance v. Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v) and [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit).